# SQL leave only rows with numbers that don't sum to zero

Tags: sql, ms-access, sum

I have the following problem: I have a table in which there are the following values:

- ID : VALUE
- 1 : 900
- 2 : -900
- 3 : 900
- 4 : 900

I would like to make a query that 'cancels' the rows that add to zero, here for example 1 and 2 or 2 and 3 or 2 and 4 so at the end I can have the following table of values

- 900
- 900

but NOT the sum of them (1800) I want them separately, I don't care about which Id it picks just want the numbers that don't add to zero, thanks!

---

Hello everyone thanks for the help, yes in fact I would like to see if there is a solution in plain basic SQL (klin answer is excellent but looks like it has a Postgres custom function unnest) so that is why I was trying to do this in Access, the reason is that one day in the work someone came to me with this problem (some finance guy, you know, they have the strangest requirements) and I figured out a way of doing this on Excel and VBA but I was wondering if there was a way of doing this straight on SQL, thanks again! and for melpomene's comment, no, 400,500 and -900 should not cancel, only pairs with same value, opposite sign, thank you.

Comment: This does not seem like the kind of thing a database is designed for, and it also doesn´t seem like a practical way to store data. You might want to explain WHY you need this, so that we can point you in the right direction.

Comment: I removed the extraneous database tags.  Please tag he problem with the database you are actually using.

Comment: What if the values are `400`, `500`, and `-900`? Should that cancel out?

Comment: Thanks kiln, worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that we are looking for pairs of rows with opposite values.

Example data (Postgres).

```
create table test (id int, val int);
insert into test values 
    (1, 900), (2, -900), (3, 900), (4, 900),
    (5, -400), (6, 400), (7, -400), (8, -400);

select * from test;

 id | val  
----+------
  1 |  900
  2 | -900
  3 |  900
  4 |  900
  5 | -400
  6 |  400
  7 | -400
  8 | -400
(8 rows)
```

Query:

```
delete from test
where id in (
    select unnest(array[id1, id2])
    from (
        select distinct on (id1) *
        from ( 
            select t1.id id1, t2.id id2
            from test t1
            join test t2
            on t1.val + t2.val = 0 and t1.id < t2.id and t1.val > 0
            ) s1
        ) s2
);
```

Result:

```
select * from test;

 id | val  
----+------
  3 |  900
  4 |  900
  5 | -400
  8 | -400
(4 rows)
```

---

You can try the query without specific Postgres functionalities:

```
delete from test
where id in (
    select id1 
    from (
        select id1, min(id2) id2
        from (
            select t1.id id1, t2.id id2
            from test t1
            join test t2
            on t1.val + t2.val = 0 and t1.id < t2.id and t1.val > 0
            ) s1
        group by id1
        ) s2
    union all
    select id2
    from (
        select id1, min(id2) id2
        from (
            select t1.id id1, t2.id id2
            from test t1
            join test t2
            on t1.val + t2.val = 0 and t1.id < t2.id and t1.val > 0
            ) s1
        group by id1
        ) s3
);
```

Use common table expression (`with` statement) for the subquery if your server can accept this.